# Enabing RLS and create policy. PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, roles, privileges, row-level-security

I have a problem while trying to enable rls for a login role I created. When I log in with sergio credintials the table doesn't respond.

[image: RLS Enable and Create policy]

Comment: What do you mean with "table doesn't respond"? What is the query you run that "doesn't respond"? Do get an error if yes, which one? Do you see to many rows? Do you see not enough rows? Does pgAdmin stop respoding?

Comment: I see nothing. I got this : Query returned successfully with no result. Is there a PGSQL version problem or mine ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did it :P